# Is there a name for the pattern of a application 'system user'

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

I have previously worked on a project that offered custom competitions to it's users. The users could create their own competition and have other members participate. In addition to that, the company which owned the software also created competitions which all members could participate.

This was implemented using a "System User". A user in the system which represented the application rather than a real user.

I am wondering if there is a formal name for this pattern and also if there are alternatives to this. The system user will not behave in the same way as a regular user of the system might so perhaps there is a different approach that separates the role of system user from that of a regular user in the application.

Any ideas are very welcome!

Comment: System User reminds me of Community: http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community

Comment: Great example! Thats the sort of thing I'm thinking of. Theres not really a reason for that 'User' to exist other than for it to carry out some user related tasks. Its not really a user in the true sense. I suppose its a very common approach if SO are doing it. Is there a name for this? How could we name it?

Comment: Thinking about some of the reasons why this is not an ideal approach, assuming we want to perform some presentation on all users, an exception would have to be made for the system user. You might not want them counted as a 'member', randomly chosen as a raffle winner, appear in 'friend' searches etc. lots of exceptions need to be made, and possibly lots of if statements...something everyone likes to avoid

Comment: The code you would end up with by using such a "pattern" would violate many nice gems explained here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc